# How to increase channelMessage max size with simpleWebRTC SDK

Tags: webrtc, simplewebrtc

I got this error after sending message via webrtc, the message contents file image.

```
Message too large (can send a maximum of 262144 bytes)
```

How can I achieve this one. Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Comment: This how you can do in webRTC, not sure how you can do this with simplewebrtc.
https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/large-data-channel-messages/

Answer (score 1):

This is done by splitting the file into several chunks and then reassembling on the other end. https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/datachannel/filetransfer/ shows how.